# How to set up networking on a per-user basis?

Tags: linux, networking, users, vpn, multiuser

I would like to set up access to corporate VPN for just my user account on my computer; not for the other accounts and certainly not for the guest user.

To achieve this, I presume, I need to configure networking on a per-user basis. How can I do this?

I would like to use Ubuntu operating system, if possible. I am just figuring out how to approach setting up VPN correctly; I did not set up any.

Comment: Please add more details, like your OS, a list of your user accounts, current VPN configuration...

Comment: For linux have a look at [network namespaces](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/).